# Can I use a symbol other than the equal sign in self-documenting f-strings

Tags: python, f-string

Self-documenting f-strings in Python allow you to write a print statement like this:

```py
print(f"{result=}")
```

This works fine, but the `=` sign is not just used to tell Python you want a self-documenting f-string...it is also the symbol that gets formatted into the output. Is there any way to get Python to use the `:` character instead of the `=` character in the *output* of self-documenting f-strings, maybe something like this:

```py
print(f"{result:}")
```

Comment: `:` already has another meaning in f-strings, it separates the variable from the format specifier.

Comment: You can use other symbols if you want different behaviour and/or errors, sure.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any way to customize the formatting of self-documenting f-strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe As a newcomer to Python (but not to coding), it seems reasonable to me that Python would expect me to use the equal sign (and only the equal sign) to tell it that I want a self-documenting f-string. The part that seems strange is that it would also require me to use that same symbol in the literal output of the print statement. Am I odd for thinking this way?

Comment: "Prefer the look of" is not something languages usually accommodate, excepting, perhaps, Perl.

Comment: @tadman Again, I'm a Python noob, but doesn't the print() function supply the `sep` parameter already so that you can do just that? (use the separator that you prefer the look of?)

Comment: for not too complicated stuffs maybe this could be useful `print(f"{result=}".replace('=', ':', 1))` (you make a custom partial function for this purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to change the way self-documenting f-strings are formatted. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) explains:

> When the equal sign `'='` is provided, the output will have the expression text, the `'='` and the evaluated value. Spaces after the opening brace `'{'`, within the expression and after the `'='` are all retained in the output. By default, the `'='` causes the `repr()` of the expression to be provided, unless there is a format specified. When a format is specified it defaults to the `str()` of the expression unless a conversion `'!r'` is declared.

As you can see, the `=` in the output is fixed by the specification.

I don't know the process of requesting changes to the language, but this seems like it would be a reasonable request. But for now you'll have to format it manually, like you've had to do before 3.12.